# plot proportion change ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I want to plot the proportion of `datetime` column for each day using a histogram. For example, the first day has a count of 6 and the second day has 3 and the third day has 7, and I want to plot the proportion pr percentage of change from the first day to the second day and the second day to third day and do the same for the rest of the data.

code

```
data <- read.table("input.csv", sep=",", head=T)
data$datetime <- as.Date(data$datetime)
ggplot(data, aes(x=datetime)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white")   +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count..+1,
               label=ifelse(..count..!=0, ..count.., NA)), geom='text', binwidth = 0.5, size=3)+ 
  #scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 day")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",  date_labels = "%b-%d-%y")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size=6))
```

input.csv

```
index,datetime,value,type
461,2020-03-03 00:00:00,1.9942995846439968,x
462,2020-03-03 01:00:00,2.1268067887438273,x
463,2020-03-03 02:00:00,2.465004647476598,x
464,2020-03-03 04:00:00,2.6925364129228964,x
465,2020-03-03 10:00:00,2.9067051924252225,x
466,2020-03-03 23:00:00,3.15486048056035,x
467,2020-03-04 04:00:00,3.129483871690328,x
468,2020-03-04 05:00:00,2.9299302120270583,x
469,2020-03-04 07:00:00,2.8233925583949744,x
470,2020-03-05 02:00:00,2.7136509773224926,x
471,2020-03-05 03:00:00,2.414295826379634,x
472,2020-03-05 04:00:00,2.3617177577192523,x
473,2020-03-05 05:00:00,2.3603488433328494,x
474,2020-03-05 06:00:00,2.3820833128692214,x
475,2020-03-05 17:00:00,2.376124347303893,x
476,2020-03-05 18:00:00,2.4256585822020846,x
477,2020-03-06 03:00:00,2.363671952946105,x
478,2020-03-06 05:00:00,2.431267806961426,x
479,2020-03-06 06:00:00,2.5549387862153146,x
480,2020-03-06 07:00:00,2.607673788605378,x
481,2020-03-06 14:00:00,2.670112987652902,x
482,2020-03-06 16:00:00,2.9147875278302138,x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tends to be easiest to do as much processing before making the plot. Here I calculate the number of cases per day and the change between days and then plot it. As I pre-calculated the counts, I can use `geom_col` rather than `geom_histogram`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- read_csv("index,datetime,value,type
461,2020-03-03 00:00:00,1.9942995846439968,x
462,2020-03-03 01:00:00,2.1268067887438273,x
463,2020-03-03 02:00:00,2.465004647476598,x
464,2020-03-03 04:00:00,2.6925364129228964,x
465,2020-03-03 10:00:00,2.9067051924252225,x
466,2020-03-03 23:00:00,3.15486048056035,x
467,2020-03-04 04:00:00,3.129483871690328,x
468,2020-03-04 05:00:00,2.9299302120270583,x
469,2020-03-04 07:00:00,2.8233925583949744,x
470,2020-03-05 02:00:00,2.7136509773224926,x
471,2020-03-05 03:00:00,2.414295826379634,x
472,2020-03-05 04:00:00,2.3617177577192523,x
473,2020-03-05 05:00:00,2.3603488433328494,x
474,2020-03-05 06:00:00,2.3820833128692214,x
475,2020-03-05 17:00:00,2.376124347303893,x
476,2020-03-05 18:00:00,2.4256585822020846,x
477,2020-03-06 03:00:00,2.363671952946105,x
478,2020-03-06 05:00:00,2.431267806961426,x
479,2020-03-06 06:00:00,2.5549387862153146,x
480,2020-03-06 07:00:00,2.607673788605378,x
481,2020-03-06 14:00:00,2.670112987652902,x
482,2020-03-06 16:00:00,2.9147875278302138,x")

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(datetime)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/lag(n))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = date, y = n, label = round(prop, 2))) +
  geom_col()   +
  geom_text(nudge_y = 0.1) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",  date_labels = "%b-%d-%y")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size=6))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>